# OutOfMemoryError: how to solve this

Tags: android, eclipse

When I run eclipse(adt-bundle) I get this error:

`!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-05-07 12:29:12.500

!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`

Even when I changed the RAM size it showed this error.
Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: post code and the whole stacktrace if you want us to help you

Comment: This is an old problem, particularly for older versions of Eclipse and older JREs. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allow the JVM to use more memory using the -Xmx VM argument.

For instance, to allow the [JVM](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/) to use 1 GB (1024 MB) of memory:

`java -Xmx1024m`

Comment: PermGen space is not the same as the general heap space.